# Flex - how to download a string variable as a file to the local machine?

Tags: string, apache-flex, flash-builder, savefiledialog

I have a String variable in my flex (flash builder 4) application containing CSV data.   I need to allow the user to download this data to a local file.  For example, giving them a "csv" button to click and it might present them with a save file dialog (and I would be sending the contents of my string variable).

Is this possible / how ?

I am using the ResuableFX component for the datagrid to csv.    This the code I ended up with that works to save the string to a text file for the user (in a web browser):

```
var dg2CSV:DataGrid2CSV = new DataGrid2CSV();
dg2CSV.includeHeader=true;
dg2CSV.target=adgEncounters;
var csvText:String=dg2CSV.getCSV();

var MyFile:FileReference = new FileReference();
var csvFileNameDT:String = QuickDateFormatter.format(new Date().toString(),"YYYYMMDDJJNNSS");
MyFile.save(csvText,"Encounters"+csvFileNameDT+".csv");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in an AIR App you can use File.[browseForSave()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#browseForSave%28%29).

If you're in a web app, you can use [FileReference.save()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29) .  The [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) docs have a lot more info on this.

In many cases, I would recommend using [navigateToURL()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29) to open the file outside of Flash and let the browser deal with it.

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this without user interaction.